# Is there any difference between Ubuntu and Centos 7 when running su -c “my command” “someuser” ？

Tags: ubuntu, centos, su, portability

I tried below command in both Ubuntu and Centos 7:

```
su -c  "./bin/server"  swrun
```

and I found it's started process by root in Ubuntu, but started process by `swrun` in Centos 7.

I used service scripts under /etc/init.d in Centos 7 to run this command, but conf file under /etc/init in Ubuntu to run this command. Is there any difference for these 2 ways?

Any difference between Ubuntu and Centos 7? Or any mistake in my command?

Thanks for your suggestions!

---

some part of my conf script in ubuntu :

```
script
    sh /usr/share/huiertep_setup/script/run_selfcheck.sh
    sh /usr/share/huiertep_setup/script/run_raid_status_check.sh
    ROOT_DB_PASSWORD='abd32532@het'
    
    echo "SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1" | mysql -u root -p${ROOT_DB_PASSWORD}
    cd /usr/share/server
    su -c "./bin/server" swrun
end script
```

but make me confused is that I run `su -c "./bin/server" swrun`  outside of this script, it's process started still by root !

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? It may also be useful to know the exact way you are using that command in your `init` files.

Comment: Ubuntu 16 I used 。

Comment: The config you give and the path /etc/init mean you are using Upstart on Ubuntu, while CentOS 7 uses systemd.  They are two different init systems, which is the core part of a Linux OS. Is there any chance that the “swrun” user has a UID of 0 on the Ubuntu system?

Comment: Can we assume that you have not posted a real password to a live database in this question?

Comment: hi, jsbillings ,I think you re correct . I checked /etc/passwd in both ubuntu and centos7,the info of swrun are different :  swrun:x:0:0::/home/swrun:   (ubnutu)    swrun:x:1001:0::/home/swrun:/bin/bash (centos7)   .   so how can I make "swrun"  user has a UID of 0 on centos7 when I create  it ? thanks a lot !